# React.js styled-components importing images and using them as div background

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components and am trying to set a background image like so

```
const HeaderImage= styled.div`
    background-image: url('../../assets/image.png');
';
```

I've also tried without the quotes, like so

```
const HeaderImage= styled.div`
        background-image: url(../../assets/image.png);
 ';
```

In both cases, I get the same result

http://localhost:3000/assets/image.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I am using [Richard Kall's react starter](https://github.com/richardkall/react-starter)

The file is definitely in the specified location.

Am I loading it incorrectly?

I should mention, I'm very new to this (React, and styled-components)

Comment: Could you try opening `http://localhost:3000/assets/image.png` in your browser?

Comment: Did you try importing the image
For example: import someName from '../../assets/image.png'
The 'someName' can be replaced by any name you want

Comment: it's because your code will execute in browser, not in server, so you cant access your file system from browser. You can use 'file-loader' for webpack or serve a static folder. I think the easiest way it's https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader

Comment: @FabianSchultz, that didn't work. Image not found.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should import images in the following manner (assuming that you have webpack configured for importing media assets).

```
import myImage from '../../assets/image.png';

/* ... */

const HeaderImage = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${myImage});
`;
```

Comment: I needed to explicitly give the `height` and `width` attributes too.

Comment: @IsaacPak so `background-size` css parameter then? Treat styled component as your normal css basically.

Comment: @Ilja what if you want to import images dynamically?

Comment: @inker as from url? just use url in `background-image` ? Its same as you would with css

Comment: What if I'm providing urls as a prop to HeaderImage element in render()?

Comment: @developer assuming you pas it like this `<HeaderImage someUrl="https://.... />"` you can access this prop in styles via `background-image: url(${props => props.someUrl})`

Comment: This guy answers after me, copies part of my answer, answers incorrectly and gets the correct answer ???

Comment: @TelmoDias Use case in your answer focuses on styled image component. Question is about using image assets as background image source of a div. Besides importing asset, our answers cover different things.

Comment: @Ilja sorry but then you should also update the title of the questions which states nothing about background-images... "importing images in React.js with styled-components"

Comment: This works in the case of having css determined at the component level, but what if the css is dynamically generated from elsewhere, and simply added in .elm { ${myDynamicCss}}. Really I want a path solution, that I can reference my dist/ folder as the root path of where my assets sit.

Comment: For production it won't matter because the files will be sitting on the server and can be self referenced but to fix the path with webpack-server instead of importing:   devServer: {
    contentBase: dist,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    before: app => {
      app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets')));
    }

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT :** this answer was edited after the question title was updated, due to misleading question title.

Using image as background-image CSS property :

```
import LogoSrc from './assets/logo.png';

/* ... */

const LogoDiv = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${LogoSrc});
  /* width and height should be set otherwise container will have either have them as 0 or grow depending on its contents */
`;

/* ... */

<LogoDiv />
```

Normal way of importing and using images :

```
import LogoSrc from './assets/logo.png';

/* ... */

const Logo = styled.img`
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
`;

/* ... inside the render or return of your component ... */

<Logo src={LogoSrc} />
```

**EDIT 2:** For reference there is another way to use styled-components, mostly used when using components that you already import (i.e. ant-design components of from other component library) or in case of components that don't work using `styled._cp_name_` notation.

**NOTE:** components need to be compatible with styled-components.

Imagine you would export Logo on a file and import it on another component file :

```
const Logo = styled.img`
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
`;

export default Logo;
```

Then, on the file where you would import it, you could add more styles by :

```
import Logo from '../components/Logo';

const L = styled(Logo)`
   border: 1px dashed black;
`;

/* ... then inside render or return ... */
<L />
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import logo from 'public/images/logo.jpg';

/* ... */

const HeaderImg = styled.img.attrs({
  src: `${logo}`
})`
width: 50px;
height: 30px;
`;
```

Comment: for static logo this method is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Importing files is one way of doing it as is suggested above, but it isn't the only way.

Here is an alternative solution, referencing file paths, the original way, using a custom express extension to target your dist folder. (Personally I prefer this approach because it keeps the css clean from the jsx and is self readable)

*Disclaimer:*
This solution is for webpack-dev-server for testing, but once the code is deployed, as long as you have generated your assets with your dist folder it will work by default.

Example:

**component.tsx**

```js
const Button = styled.button`
  background: url('/assets/file.svg');
`
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
{
  devServer: {
    contentBase: dist,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    before: app => {
      app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(dist, '/assets')));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, if you will use "/assets/.." pattern it works in the production, but fails for webpackDevServer..

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking a dynamic solution, you can also make something work with the `<img>` element. Some psuedo code that could make this possible:

```js
// styles.tsx

import styled from "styled-components";

export const Relative = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;
//using the img function is no more supported
export const Image = styled.img`
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
`;

export const TextInFrontOfImage = styled.p`
  z-index: 1;
`;


// index.tsx

//..

<Relative>
  <Image src={props.url}></Image>
  <TextInFrontOfImage>Lorem Ipsum</TextInFrontOfImage>
</Relative>
```

Using some combination of position: relative/absolute and z-index you should be able to achieve similar results to the `background-image` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to a component like this:

```
 export const ImgTop = styled.div`
        display: block;
        background-image: ${props => `url(${props.background})`};
        background-size: cover;
        
    `
    <ImgTop background={urlimagen}></ImgTop>
```