# background image in styled components react

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Good evening.

I am facing an issue while using react in combination with styled components.

I have an image folder located in :

[image]

And I have my styled components in the following folder :

[image]

Inside the styled components I'm trying to import the image like this :

```
const FormImage = styled.div`
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -20%;
    background-image: url(../../img/testlogo.png);
`;
```

Im sure this is the right path. But somehow the image is not showing in the browser.

This is what i'm seeing in my browser :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346413/importing-images-in-react-js-with-styled-components

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such path is not available in runtime (as CSS-in-JS like `styled-component` creates the CSS in runtime, although there are solutions with no-runtime), you should try one of the next approaches:

```
import ImgSrc from '../../img/testlogo.png';
const FormImage = styled.div`
    background-image: url(${ImgSrc});
`;

// or
const FormImage = styled.div`
    background-image: url(${require(`../../img/testlogo.png`)});
`;
```