# Can't get a buttons background image to display

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Tried searching for an answer on this but didn't find anything that worked.

Im working in React, using styled-components.

Got a styles.js file that contains all my css for a component I'm working on. Problem is, I'm trying to put an image of a dice on a set of buttons.
The buttons are used in the component as:

```
<Button></Button>
```

If I want to overwrite a particular buttons style, I have rules (as props I think?) in the same styles.js file. Here's what this specific problem button is:

```
// Style override for a Randomiser Button
${props => props.RANDButton && css`
background: transparent url('../Images/D20.png') no-repeat;

width: 50px;
height: 50px;

border: outset 1px;
border-radius: 0px;
`}
```

Here's the 'original' code that all buttons use unless overwritten:

```
//style(s) for a button
export const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: rgb(100,250,100);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  color: black;

  border: outset;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: Center;
  width: auto;
  
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
...
*Other css rules*
...
`;
```

Then, this specific button is used like so:

```
<Button RANDButton></Button>
```

Sorry, I can't recall the proper terminology for this method.

When I save, and the component re-renders, it doens't show the image

[image: Screenshot of Component not displaying button image]

If I've missed something basic, please could someone point it out to me?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `transparent` property on `background` for?

Comment: Experimenting. Wanted to try something other than `background: url...` to make sure I hadn't screwed up some other part of the CSS

Comment: `background: url(http://address-of-img)` or `background: url(filePath)` should perfectly work on its own. But make sure your image is the right size too (with the help of `background-size`)! I reproduced a (really) simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bash-y6q49

Comment: Thanks. This didn't fix it but it did get me thinking. Turns out images need to be explicity imported so they can be displayed as webpack minifies images and changes the urls.
Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56404570/2796017

Comment: Glad I could at least help with the thinking process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that images, unless explicity imported as:

```
import D20 from './Images/D20.png';
```

and then used as:

```
  background: url(${D20});
```

...will be minified and have their URL changed thanks to webpack.

Found answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56404570/2796017

Answer (score 0):

it's duplicate question , you can find the right answer in below link
[React.js styled-components importing images and using them as div background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346413/react-js-styled-components-importing-images-and-using-them-as-div-background)